# Sort columns in dataframe based on float suffix in headers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = [{'Po_+0.00': 1, 'Po_+0.25': 1.5, 'Po_+0.50': 2,'Po_-0.25': 1.3, 'Po_-0.50': 1.6}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index =[1])
```

[image]
My goal is to to sort the columns like that:

[image]

I tried various ways but never managed to get the correct result.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sorted` with parameter `key` and lambda function for convert next `3` values to floats:

```
df = df[sorted(df.columns, key=lambda x: float(x[3:]))]
print (df)
   Po_-0.50  Po_-0.25  Po_+0.00  Po_+0.25  Po_+0.50
1       1.6       1.3         1       1.5         2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `argsort` taking numerical part of column names:

```
df = df[df.columns[df.columns.str[3:].astype(float).argsort()]]
#Alternative
#df = df.iloc[:, df.columns.str[3:].astype(float).argsort()]

print(df)
   Po_-0.50  Po_-0.25  Po_+0.00  Po_+0.25  Po_+0.50
1       1.6       1.3         1       1.5         2
```

Comment: Both of the answers worked fine, I only selected @jezrael solution as it is more flexible in case the columns have different length and a .find() can be used to find for example where the numerical part starts.